# derivative of $e^{\ln x^2}-3x^7$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponentiation

$$e^{\ln x^2}-3x^7$$

The first term: $=e^v$
$v=\ln x^2=u^2$

$v\;'=2uu\;'=(2\ln x)\dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{2\ln x}{x}$

$\dfrac{e^{\ln x^2}2\ln x}{x}
+21x^{-8}$

How do I simplify further? I don't understand why the first term turns out to be $2x$

Comment: Hint: $e^{\log y}=y$, simplify at the very beginning.

Comment: This is the same function as $x^2-3x^7$ when $x\neq0$, and not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: Keep in mind how the logarithm is defined:
If exp(x) = y, then ln(y) = x --> exp(ln(y)) = y

Comment: @Milly So if I don't simplify at the very beginning it is wrong? How I solved it is wrong?

Comment: You wrote $\ln x^2=u^2$. So are you saying that you have $e^{(\ln x)^2}$? $\ln x^2$ is usually interpreted as $\ln(x^2)$, not $(\ln x)^2$.

Comment: @alex.jordan So $e^{2\ln x}=2x$? thanks

Comment: No. $e^{2\ln x}$ is not $2x$. I didn't say anything that implied that. If $x$ is positive, then $e^{2\ln x}=e^{\ln x^2}=x^2$. If $x$ is negative, then $e^{\ln x^2}=x^2$ and $e^{2\ln x}$ is undefined. If $x$ is $0$, then $e^{2\ln x}$ and $e^{\ln x^2}$ are both undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $$e^{\ln a}=a$$
Now the derivative should be trivial.

Comment: So how I solved it is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, sorry. the solution is 2x-21x^6

Comment: So $e^{2\ln x}=2x$?

Comment: ok, but then wouldn't the derivative be $2xe$, and not $2x$?

Comment: My statement was wrong. Let me try again:

$$e^{2lnx}=e^{ln{x^2}}=x^2$$
of which, the derivative is 2x.

Comment: is it $e^{\ln(x^2)}-3x^7$?

Comment: The thing to be differentiated? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

$v=\ln x^2=u^2$  ??
it would be right if $(ln x)^2$

it should be $v=\ln x^2=2u$

Comment: So $e^{2\ln x}=2x$?